# 17002 error in sql developer and exception while running application on sts localhost

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

All things were working file till yesterday, but now I'm getting 17002 error while connection to sql developer while with sql plus I can login

- Tnsping :ok
- reinstalled:same error
- listner: running
- server:localhost

Please help.

Comment: Is SQL Developer using TNS, and if not are the connection settings the same as the TNS that works? I'd guess maybe it was set up with your PC's external IP and that has now changed; though the listener is localhost-only by default so perhaps not. Maybe add both sets of connection values to the question?

Comment: if the problem was only in sql developer then it should have worked in spring tool suite but there i am getting exception while connection :(

Comment: TNS ping and SQL*Plus may be using your TNS settings (from `tnsnames.ora`), while SQL Developer and Spring are using a different connection method. Without seeing your `tnsnames.ora` and the connection settings you're using in other tools it's impossible to say what is different, and why one works but not the other. The full error message/exception you get in both would be helpful too. (Please add those things as an edit to the question, not as comments).